# How can I hide my familiar as a pact of the chain warlock?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock

I'm a Warlock, Pact of Chain. I can summon an imp with my find familiar spell.

I tried to rob a bank with my imp in mouse form. The imp got caught by an Archmage in the bank.  The imp will be testifying in a trial against me.  (I will be in a court of law).  He is telling everybody that I wanted to steal from the bank.  I tried to send my imp back to his but my DM said that the Archmage has total control over my imp, and that he is trapped in my dimension.

The imp is in the Archmage's hands.  Is there a way to send my imp away or can I do something else?  I must stop him from testifying or they are gonna kill me.

Comment: Have you read the actual spell? Is there something preventing you from using the Action options in the spell description?

Comment: Sounds like the Archmage is doing a Man in the Middle attack on your connection :)

Comment: @PastaVonTonno If there are particular conditions that are set on your familiar **you have to put them in the question**. For example, the fact that the Archmage has control  over him is one thing that should be in the question. What other conditions are there? Are the imp and you in the same dimension? Is a particular spell blocking the communication between you and your familiar? This is important, since without any special conditions it seems just a problem of not understanding the rules.

Comment: When you say "taking a trial" do you mean that he is in a court of law or something?

Comment: Yes he is in a court of law , he has being called as a witness aganist my crime

Comment: What is your level?  What Invocations have you chosen up to this point?  I ask because an Archmage is an 18th level spell caster, per the rule book.  (SRD in this case).  That means he has access to 9th level spells.

Comment: Yes kill me or put me in to the jail forever

Comment: OK,  are you playing solo or are there other characters in your party who can help?

Comment: I'm level 5 Warlock ( fiend  pact) and I dont have any invocations beside the find familair. I have a lot of spells but i cant use them in prison.

Comment: There are others 4 members in the party, they have already tried to help me but my deposit  is too high and i have against me my own imp as witness.

Comment: a 5th level Warlock has three Eldritch Invocations.   That is shown on the spell table for Warlock under "invocations known."  Pact of the Chain's find familiar  is not an Eldritch Invocation.  "Pact of the Chain ... 
You learn the find familiar spell and can cast it as a ritual. The spell doesn’t count against your number of spells known."

Comment: Without an explanation on what is keeping your warlock in your dimension, I'm afraid this isn't answerable

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### You Control Your Familiar

Rules as written, you command your familiar.  Telling him to stop should be sufficient -- which you can do telepathically if he is within 100 ft. (or have *Voice of Chain Master* Invocation):

> Your familiar acts independently of you, but it always obeys your commands.

### You can Send Your Familiar Back its Pocket Dimension

You can take a single action, 6 seconds, to send the familiar back to the pocket dimension.

> As an action, you can temporarily dismiss your familiar. It disappears into a pocket dimension where it awaits you summons.

### Re-summon It

Or, re-summon it into a different form that can't talk.

> You can’t have more than one familiar at a time. If you cast this spell while you already have a familiar, you instead cause it to adopt a new form.

### Voice of the Chain Master

Alternatively, if you have taken the invocation Voice of the Chain Master, you can take over his mouth:

> Additionally, while perceiving through your familiar's senses, you can also speak through your familiar in your own voice, even if your familiar is normally incapable of speech.

### Kill Him

Killing your Imp will send him back to his pocket dimension.

> When the familiar drops to 0 hit points, it disappears, leaving behind no physical form. It reappears after you cast this spell again.

### Dispel Magic

If your party has someone who can cast Dispel Magic, you can dispel him, in theory.  But if you could do that, you could just dispel the hold the archmage has over him.

> Choose any creature, object, or magical effect within range. Any spell of 3rd level or lower on the target ends. For each spell of 4th level or higher on the target, make an ability check using your spellcasting ability. The DC equals 10 + the spell’s level. On a successful check, the spell ends.

Comment: I tired to send my imp back but my master said the Archmage has the total control over him and my imp is trapped in my dimension.

Comment: This answer can be improved by answering the direct question of quitting the pact feature, which the book does not give option to do.

Comment: Slagmoth "Quit my familar" I thought meant to get rid of him temporarily, not drop the feature....  But I'll text about that, too.

Comment: Yes I want to get rid of him temporarily, I know I cant undone my pact of chain.

Comment: If "the Archmage has the total control over him" then your DM has gone far enough out of the rules as written for us to help any further. You'll need to ask your DM what the rules are in your game.

Comment: Can the Archmage completely cut off my control over the imp ? I dont think it is possible

Comment: @PastaVonTonno If your DM says it is so, then at his table it is so.  Are you looking for an argument/position based on the rules that you can present to the DM to tell him that you believe you are able to use your action to send the imp back?  If so, J.A's answer suffices.  If you have already had that conversation, and the DM still rules that "The Archmage has control" then the case of Rule 0 has come into play.  The DM has that latitude in D&D.  It is also possible that the Archmage has a magic item or a spell that you are not familiar with that is holding this imp in this dimension.

Comment: Korvin is right.  The DM can make the Archmage able to do anything.  The rules are a guide for the DM, but the DM has final say over your world.

Comment: Understood, thanks for all the answers and your disponibility

Comment: @DerekStucki I know the post is old and closed, but I'd just like to point out that I don't think the DM went out of the rules. I think the Archmage cast Planar Binding on the Imp, as the DM probably considered him a fiend. (I have yet to find anything on whether or not you can choose between the celestial, fey, or fiend type options for extra familiars from Pact of the Chain)

Comment: Just a couple of notes on this answer -- dismissing and resummoning the familiar are done quickly as actions, but do not change the form of the familiar; to change his form you have to actually cast the spell.  Likewise, if your familiar is killed, he does not go into his pocket dimension; his spirit goes somewhere else, and you must cast the spell again to bring him back.

Comment: My resummon heading talks about not sending him to a pocket dimension, but just recasting Find Familiar to change his forms.  The spell doesn't say if it is killed if it goes to the pocket dimension or somewhere else, I suppose my answers assume the pocket dimension which seems the logical conclusion of the rest of the spell; but the point was killing the imp makes the problem go away until you can resummon him.

Answer (score 7):

Some other ideas:

**Kill your familiar**. Get within 100ft of it and cast a damaging touch spell through the familiar targeting itself.

**Kill your character**. Once you die, all your spells and effects cease. *Of course, make sure you have a (reliable) caster standing ready with raise dead.*

**Talk to your patron**. After all, that imp is not actually yours, it is your patron's. What do They think about this upstart wizard coercing their familiar to act against their pacted servant?

If all else fails:

Throw a tantrum. Accuse the GM of changing the rules without telling you, just to screw over your character.

OK, the last one is tongue-in-cheek, but there is a bit of truth to it. After all, the GM *has* changed the rules.